# Copy a filtered range to another sheet without the header with copyTo function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering

Im sorry if im asking something that has been resolved, but i read a lot and still cannot find the answer.

Im trying to copy a filtered range to another sheet with copyTo function on AppScripts but i cannot dismiss the header.

Here's the code:

```
function newColumnFormula() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX").getSheetByName("XXX");
var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX").getSheetByName("XXX");
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.insertColumnAfter(lastColumn);

var formula = "=T2-G2";
var newColumnRange = sheet.getRange(2, lastColumn + 1, lastRow - 1, 1);
newColumnRange.setFormula(formula); 

sheet.getDataRange().createFilter();
var filterCriteria = 
SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThan(30).build();
sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(lastColumn + 1, filterCriteria);

var filteredRange = sheet.getFilter().getRange(); 
var targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
filteredRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);}
```

Tried with slice(1) and shift() but realized that it does not work with copyTo.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A sample table would be helpful in this context with dummy data, and also are you trying to copy the values to another separate Spreadsheet File, or you are only copying the values on the same file but on a different sheet tab instead?

Answer (score 1):

**SUGGESTION:**

Changed this code:

```
var filteredRange = sheet.getFilter().getRange();
```

To this code:

```
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
```

Since you would need to only copy the filtered data without including the column headers.

**Full code sample:**

```
function newColumnFormula() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");

var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.insertColumnAfter(lastColumn);

var formula = "=T2-G2";
var newColumnRange = sheet.getRange(2, lastColumn + 1, lastRow - 1, 1);
newColumnRange.setFormula(formula); 

sheet.getDataRange().createFilter();
var filterCriteria = 
SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberGreaterThan(30).build();
sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(lastColumn + 1, filterCriteria);

var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
var targetLastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
rangeToCopy.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetLastRow, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

}
```

Let me know if you have any further clarifications as these samples are based on my understanding of your post.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. Yes i am trying to copy the values to a different sheet tab in the same file. I tried with the changes of the code but still getting the data pasted with the header.

I've also tried with [var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(3, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());] to see if anything changes but the header it's always carried on to the target sheet.